# Passing json from one Backbone view to another

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

can you please explain how can i return dynamic json from one view to another?
in first view i generate json.push like this:

```
json.push({
     first: value,
     second: value
 });
```

Comment: You'll have to define "view" and "backbone" to us...

Comment: Through a global event bus may be your best bet. It would be helpful if you posted the view code. You could even go a step further and show us what you have tried and where you are stuck exactly..

Comment: @AlexisWilke: http://backbonejs.org

Comment: You can use some Controller as JSON owner, passing it to both vies, as event a async you may have problems with using receiving data from event

Answer (score 0):

Maybe jQuery events would be useful for this? For example:

**View 1:**

```
$(document).on("someEvent", function() {
    // some handler code here
});
```

**View 2:**

```
$(document).triggerHandler("someEvent", [{
    first: value,
    second: value
}]);
```

Answer (score 0):

View 1

```
$("body").trigger( "return", {})
```

View 2

```
$( "body" ).on( "return", function( event, o ) {})
```